# Formula to extract first number in cell ignoring the remainder, however number can be one or two characters and varies

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table which has a range of codes, this varys from 1 through to 16, this is then followed by a letter, for example:

```
11A - Reconnect

15b telephone

1b reconnect

2c
```

Some data has two numbers at the beginning and some has a single number. The formula I managed to get working up to 10. after this it doesn't pull through the full number.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(J2,RIGHT(J2,LEN(J2)-MAX(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},J2),""))),"")
```

I've tried to add "11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16" to the formula and that doesn't work either.

I'm sure this is probably something really simple so apologies if I'm sounding a little dumb but I've tried everything I can think of with no luck.

My formula to extract the letter seems to work fine:

```
=IF(L2="INVALID CODE","",LEFT(TEXTAFTER(J2, L2),1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

[image]

```
IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(A1,2)*1),LEFT(A1,2)*1,LEFT(A1,1)*1)
```

So the isnumber checks for 2 numbers as the first two characters, if that evaluates to false then the left() takes 1 character.

So, these versions keep the character:

[image]

Comment: Amazing this works perfectly however its now nocked the letter extraction part out, it no longer picks up some of the letters if its after 11, so 12, 13, 14, 15 and 16 it no longer picks the letter out would you know why or how to resolve that?

Comment: I would apply the same trick and then use mid() to get the 3rd or second character which would be the letter. However, do you get the letter with the other solutions?

Comment: Managed to get it to work, it was my own error ! Sorry! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You may still have an older version of Excel. If so, try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-LEFT(A1,{1,2}))
```

And drag down.

---

**EDIT_1**: Just noticed you have used `TEXTAFTER()`. So you do have access to dynamic arrays. Maybe you can consider:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=-IFERROR(-LEFT(A1:A4,2),-LEFT(A1:A4,1))
```

---

**EDIT_2:** Keeping the trailing character:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LEFT(A1:A4,3-+ISERR(-MID(A1:A4,2,1)))
```

Or, if your sample data would represent the format of all data:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A1:A4&" "," ")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this managed to get it all sorted with the first suggested answer , but i appreciate the time you took to assist me !

Answer (score 1):

This code is a bit awkward, but it works in Excel 2019. In this formula the first code is in cell `A2`:

```
=IF(AND(CODE(MID(A2, 2, 1)) > 47, CODE(MID(A2, 2, 1)) < 56), LEFT(A2, 2), LEFT(A2, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, managed to get it working quite quickly with the first suggestion but i appreciate the time you took to help me, I have tried your code too, and it was helpful !